# How to make Eclipse (pydev) automatically fold all comments when opening a file?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, folding

Is there a way that eclipse (edit: under windows) folds all comments and docstrings automatically when I open a python file?

Comment: I dont understand your question, doesn't PyDev automatically recognise your python file?

Comment: yy but all comments and docstrings are opened, i want to configure eclipse so all comments etc. are closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is now available in PyDev and can be enabled by going into the preferences:

`PyDev > Editor > Code Folding`

and then selecting what you want to fold initially.

i.e.:

[image: PyDev folding preferences]

Answer (score 6):

By default the loop and condition folds are disabled, to enable them go to Window -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Editor -> Code Folding. Apply code folding to all entries